# Setting dynamic amounts securely with Paypal payments with a redirection and not button?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Ok, I haven't worked with hosted buttons before, but it makes sense as they are a lot more secure.

I have looked around and been reading the docs (which aren't all that helpful) and best help I have found so far is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204999/472501); though I am still confused on where exactly to put that code?

Also, I technically don't want a "button", but the idea behind them seems what I want.

All I want to do is use the same query vars every time but just want to change the price - the price is dynamic depending on what the user selects in the form.

Additionally, I don't want a button per se, I would much prefer to redirect the user to paypal with the appropriate data but not sure how to go about doing that whilst setting a dynamic price?

If I didn't have to set a dynamic price I know I could just append the query vars for a hosted button onto a URL and then redirect to that URL, but I need to change the price and hence my question...

Comment: I _don't_ use it but [this reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#bm) should help. Seems you 'll have to make a _server side_ request (`NVP` or `SOAP`) to "create a button". The response to that request will either contain [HTML, a link, or an ID](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) Hth.

Comment: Yeah I seen those pages but it looked to me like all it does is create the html output for a button; I guess I can always just load the html onto a page and automatically submit the page via JS or something. Was hoping there would be something a bit more user friendly to use.

Comment: You _shouldn't_ do any of the hashing/encryption client side (Javascript) because if you did, you pretty much break what you're looking for - _securing_ the transaction from tampering. That's what hosted buttons do - protect from tampering. Any type of hashing/encrypting should be done server side, beyond the reach of any browser/client. Only _after_ that (already hashed/encrypted) should you consider any client side flow.

Comment: I'm aware of that - that is why I wanted to use a hosted "button"; but not actually use the button - and hence is why I said perhaps I could load the generated button code onto a page and automatically submit it. Not ideal though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out that not only does the response from the [BMUpdateButton API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMUpdateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) return the `HTML` to create a form, it also returns other data as well within the returned array.

Once you make the request it will return an array with three keys as per the **BMUpdateButton Response** section on the API page linked above.

These are:

- WEBSITECODE

  HTML code for web pages

  - EMAILLINK

This is what I was looking for; a plain link you can redirect users to

- HOSTEDBUTTONID

The id of the button.

Be advised when altering the contents of a hosted button you need to pass *all* the details of the button to it as when you created it; so as an example, if you leave out passing it an item name the item name will be blank and Paypal will allow the user to set it.

Also, an **important note** is that when you *update* the button details, it isn't just updated for that users session, it updates it within your paypal account - so the new name/price etc will affect *all* users that attempt to use it.

If you *still* would like to update the details of the button you can do that with the below:

I personally started with this class:

```
<?php

class Paypal
{
    /**
     * Last error message(s)
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_errors = array();

    /**
     * API Credentials
     * Use the correct credentials for the environment in use (Live / Sandbox)
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_credentials = array(
        'USER' => 'seller_1297608781_biz_api1.lionite.com',
        'PWD' => '1297608792',
        'SIGNATURE' => 'A3g66.FS3NAf4mkHn3BDQdpo6JD.ACcPc4wMrInvUEqO3Uapovity47p',
    );

    /**
     * API endpoint
     * Live - https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
     * Sandbox - https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_endPoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

    /**
     * API Version
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_version = '74.0';

    /**
     * Make API request
     *
     * @param string $method string API method to request
     * @param array $params Additional request parameters
     * @return array / boolean Response array / boolean false on failure
     */
    public function request($method, $params = array())
    {
        $this->_errors = array();
        if (empty($method)) { //Check if API method is not empty
            $this->_errors = array('API method is missing');
            return false;
        }

        //Our request parameters
        $requestParams = array(
                'METHOD' => $method,
                'VERSION' => $this->_version
            ) + $this->_credentials;

        //Building our NVP string
        $request = http_build_query($requestParams + $params);

        //cURL settings
        $curlOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->_endPoint,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', //CA cert file
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

        //Sending our request - $response will hold the API response
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //Checking for cURL errors
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            $this->_errors = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return false;
            //Handle errors
        } else {
            curl_close($ch);
            $responseArray = array();
            parse_str($response, $responseArray); // Break the NVP string to an array
            return $responseArray;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**Credit:** https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/

Then I did the below:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/paypal.class.php');

$paypal = new Paypal();

// Set our method
$method = 'BMUpdateButton';

// Set our params
$params = array(
    'HOSTEDBUTTONID' => 'your_button_id',
    'BUTTONTYPE' => 'BUYNOW',
    'BUTTONSUBTYPE' => 'SERVICES',
    'L_BUTTONVAR0' => 'item_name=Your Description',
    'L_BUTTONVAR1' => 'amount=999.00',
    'L_BUTTONVAR2' => 'currency_code=AUD',
    'L_BUTTONVAR3' => 'cancel_return=http://www.example.com/cancel.html',
    'L_BUTTONVAR4' => 'return=http://www.example.com/success.html'
);

// Make request to change button details
$result = $paypal->request($method, $params);
```

Note that while Paypal say that `BUTTONSUBTYPE` is optional, you will likely get an error if you don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use their button designer if you're going to do hosted buttons.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer

The security comes from IPN verification after the transaction.

See:

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside

[Validate that IPN call is from PayPal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848227/validate-that-ipn-call-is-from-paypal)

The answer on this post is a better way to do it:

[Dynamic PayPal button generation - isn't it very insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322247/dynamic-paypal-button-generation-isnt-it-very-insecure)

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware of how to create the buttons - what I'm trying to work out is how to get the correct data to pass to paypal so I can send to them via a redirect with query vars. So instead of it returning html to me to put a button on my site I would just like a query string returned or JSON or something more workable.

Answer (score 0):

Button code is HTML form tags based so you would easily convert it to a string query and assemble your dynamic payloads with this format:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=yourAccount@email.com&item_name=itemNameTest&item_number=123&amount=1&currency_code=USD&no_shipping=1
```

Customize it and append vars per the varliables listed [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), and use it with your redirection method.

*Button manager API is more comprehensive except it won't return you a query string URL like this, though the idea behind is identical to an HTML form code snippet*